# Can an angular app on AWS S3 served via cloudfront resolve to another route apart from the index route?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, frontend, amazon-cloudfront, http-status-code-403

I have an angular app hosted on S3. When I try to directly go to a route like `myapp.com/items` I get a 403 forbidden error. But when I access the app from `myapp.com` everything is okay and from the app I can navigate to `myapp.com/items`. I don't understand why this is happening.

How can I make it so that routes like `myapp.com/items` can be accessed directly and not throw an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On CloudFront distribution enter error pages tab

[image]

Then create a new error response to deal with any othe routes and redirect it to index.html file

[image]